# How to get class of pymongo database suitable for isinstance()?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a test where I'm trying to identify if I've successfully gotten an instance of a database using pymongo, and would like to use isinstance(obj, class) in an assertion.  However I cant figure out how to get a class (not instance) of the database

I've tried several approaches.  This seems closest but still no cigar:

```
import pymongo
client = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost')
database = client['test']
assert isinstance(database, pymongo.MongoClient.db_name)
```

which doesn't work since db_name isn't defined.  Pymongo docs say a new database (reference?) is made using either

```
pymongo.MongoClient.db_name
```

or

```
pymongo.MongoClient[db_name]
```

Of course these create an instance if I give it a db_name string, yet I want only the class, not an instance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is check if it is instance of [`pymongo.database.Database`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database)

```
>>> import pymongo
>>> client = pymongo.MongoClient()
>>> db = client.test
>>> isinstance(db, pymongo.database.Database)
True
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks!  And thanks for the link at the top of your answer - I never saw that as I was going down the wrong rabbit hole...